# Nautilus bookmarks are missing since upgrade to 13.04

Tags: upgrade, nautilus

My bookmarks are not shown anymore after upgrading to 13.04 Raring ringtails and I can't add any new bookmarks. The function is not shown and the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> isn't working either. Is this functionality just gone for some reason (as the split screen with <kbd>F3</kbd>) or is there something wrong with my upgrade?

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### Nautilus bookmark settings

To manage bookmarks go to the *Files* menu in the panel to open the *Bookmarks* dialog. There we may enter a name and a path of a bookmark to appear in the Nautilus left side panel in the Bookmarks section:

[image]

#### Bookmark an opened directory

Alternatively open the directory you want to bookmark. Then click on the cogwheel top right to select *"Bookmark this Location"* or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

[image]

To remove a bookmark select *"Remove""* from the right click context menu on the bookmark.

All our bookmarks will also be displayed as a quicklist:

[image]

#### Manual approach and removing default entries

Those bookmarks are stored in an editable file in `.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` where we may manually (or programmatically) add and remove path entries which take effect immediately. The examples above resulted in the following file content:

```
file:///home/takkat/Documents/test
file:///home/takkat/Music
file:///home/takkat/Pictures
file:///home/takkat/Videos
file:///home/takkat/Downloads
file:///home/takkat/Documents/My%20Bookmark My Bookmark
```

Comment: Hi, sorry but in the bookmarks dialog which i have, i can only rename or reorder my existing bookmarks which are not shown anyway. The "Bookmark this Location" entry in my menu is missing, CRTL-D is not working either (as mentioned in my question).

Comment: Sorry i am not used to this interface, i am only allowed to edit my comments for 5 minutes which seems to me a bit odd. Anyway, what is mssing in my last comment is to say thank you for your detailed answer. Do you have any other suggestions ? Am I the only person with this problem ? Thx for your help.

Comment: Ok, now i know what my problem was. I thought that the "add this location to  bookmark" will be applied to the file/folder which is selected in the file manager. Now i realized that you have to go into the folder and then call this function (as you showed in your screenshots). I am not pretty sure but i think in the previous version this worked like I was expecting it.

Comment: For me I actually don't see my bookmarks on the left panel. I have to go to the menu File > Bookmarks. Any idea how to get that to show ?

Comment: Why there is no more drag&drop functionality? Now in "Files" you can only drop into bookmarked directory other dirs/files. I would like to be able just simple drag&drop to my bookmarks like previously in Nautilus and if it's causing some problems to others then there should be disable option for it.

Comment: @JJD: http://askubuntu.com/posts/61110/

Comment: @Takkat [What application did you use to produce the screenshots?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/443309/what-application-is-used-to-create-screenshots-with-highlights)

Comment: @JJD: the shot was done on the host Ubuntu showing the VM window with default shreenshot tool using PrtSc key, then edited in Gimp. Little effort, max. outcome ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's happened to me too. But I've had a Kernel Panic problem while upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04. I was able to restore my system, but none of my previous bookmarks were available.

It seems that the default folder where Nautilus saves bookmarks has changed. I restored them by copying my previous bookmarks from the file `/home/yourusername/.gtk-bookmarks` to `/home/yourusername/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`. A simple text copy and paste using `gedit`.

Comment: oh blimey , no thanks god i had no kernel panic. My problem was a combination of the fact what you mentioned and the different logic while adding a new bookmark. thanks for your answer.

Comment: i think your answer is one puzzle piece in this "new nautilus thing" in 13.04 raring ringtails.

Comment: @YuriC see my post at bottom about those two files.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you cannot add new item from the menu, you can edit the default one and surprisingly I just realized that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will work to create a new one if you perform it in the desired location, however it is not presented in the menu.

Comment: Almost 9 years later ... getting this error launching nautilus from WSL and `CTRL`+`D` fixed it. Nice one!

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility. I had the same problem when updating to v13.04/GTK classic. The bookmark feature was simply gone. For a time, I thought that this very useful feature had just been removed. However, in the course of reconfiguring Brasero plugins I discovered the problem. I was starting Brasero from the command line since there was no menu entry created when I installed Brasero. I kept getting an error essentially telling me that Brasero couldn't access the bookmark file: `Permission Denied`. When I tried to check the permissions of `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks`, I couldn't even open the `.config` folder. It turned out that the `owner:group` of `.config` and all its children had been changed to `root:root` with no access at all given to "Other".

I then recursively changed the owner:group of `.config` to `me:me` (`sudo chown -R me:me .config`). I also changed the file mode of directories to 775 and of any files to 664. This fixed the Brasero problem and also, magically, my bookmarks were back!

Comment: @ndefontenay see this post, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

I found that in Precise 12.04, I had to modify TWO files to get all the behaviors.

$HOME/.gtk-bookmarks
This gave me the bookmarks in Nautilus

$HOME/.config/yourGTKVersion/bookmarks
This gave me bookmarks in the file opening dialog box for all other applications.

Don't know if UBUNTU will keep them synced from ths point or not. I was moving my home directory from 10.10 to a new hard drive with 12.04. I had made the mistake of running for a LOOOOOOONG time on a non LTS (Long Time Support) version. Over a 6 month period, all my repos for updates vanished. I couldn't even get the latest PHP for my version. HAD to switch. And I needed to get back to developing code QUICK, needed bookmarks, etc.

Answer (score -1):

in 13.10 I just realized that you can use CTRL+D...the shortcut is not presented in the menu but it works to create new bookmarks.