# How to remove obsolete shortcut from the Files launcher icon?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, shortcuts

The "Files" launcher icon has a set of shortcuts.

[image: Subpanel is opened on the right-click over the Files icon]

One of this is a older folder that I have removed, so the shortcut does not work and display this error:

[image: Unhandled error message: Error when getting information for file 'SHORTCUT_DIRECTORY': No such file or directory]

How can I remove this obsolete shortcut?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/293898/nautilus-bookmarks-are-missing-since-upgrade-to-13-04 - I also wrote something on how to remove a bookmark.

Comment: @Takkat Yep, it is a dupe. Could you merge it? Because here is a great answer too

Comment: Not a dupe really, you asked for **removal**, didn't you?

Comment: Oh well, yes, you are right. Initially I thought that there were no there post about it (neither recover). Your answer is showing the same menu and that was enough for me :D (sorry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open a new Nautilus window.
2. Click on "Files" on the menu bar.
3. Select "Bookmarks".

[image: screenshoot]

You will probably see the bookmark you wanted to remove there in the list.

Select it and click the <kbd>-</kbd> button.