# Quick access to /usr/share/applications

Tags: nautilus, bookmarks

I'm a Linux newbie, just installed Ubuntu yesterday as a matter of fact. I love it. But I do have one question. Is there a way to get to `/usr/share/applications` faster than having to go through the FileSystem? I tried making a Hard Link to it, but for some reason it won't let me.

Comment: Please edit your question with *how* you tried to make the hardlink. Have you tried `ln`?

Answer (score 1):

Or instead you can try *Dash*... You can view a list of all installed applications or you can type in the names for quick search...

[Unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_%28user_interface%29), the default UI since Ubuntu 11.04, has this wonderful *Dash* desktop search utility. You can access Dash by hitting the <kbd>Super</kbd> key (aka   <kbd>[image: WindowsKey]</kbd>   key in Windows keyboard).

At the bottom of the Dash, click the ***application lens*** among others, as shown in the snapshot (in *Ubuntu 12.04* you can directly access this using <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>):

[image: dash1]

Click "***Installed: See ... more results***" to view a menu list of all installed applications.

[image: dash2]

Click to launch the application you want. Use arrow keys or the scroll bar to browse for more application down the list.

[image: dash3]

---

Or you can create a **bookmark** for the directory. For this browse to the `/usr/share/applications` directory and in there press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and the bookmark will show up in the Nautilus' side bar (use <kbd>F9</kbd> to toggle side bar visibility).

[image: bookmark]

Answer (score 1):

We probably never need to open the directory `/usr/share/applications` under normal desktop usage, beacause all installed applications can easily be [accessed through the Dash](https://askubuntu.com/a/388827).

If for other reasons we often need a quick access to `/usr/share/applications` we may want to bookmark this location in Nautilus. See this question on how to do this:

- [Nautilus bookmarks are missing since upgrade to 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/293898/nautilus-bookmarks-are-missing-since-upgrade-to-13-04)

After we had made our bookmark **applications** we can quickly open it from both, a right click menu from the Launcher, and in the side pane of Nautilus:

[image]