# Remove default entries from Files (Nautilus) quicklist in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, launcher

By default, when I right click on Nautilus (Files) icon (in launcher), default places and my bookmarks are shown. Is it possible to show just my custom bookmarks?

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer in [Nautilus bookmarks are missing since upgrade to 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/293910) answer, section **Manual approach and removing default entries**. Works also for Ubuntu 13.10.

To summarize:

Bookmarks for Nautilus are stored in an editable file in ~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks where we may manually (or programmatically) add and remove path entries which take effect immediately. Bookmarks for default places in Home folder (like Pictures folder, Downloads folder,...) are also included there and can be removed and will not be autmatically recreated on login.