# How to create shortcuts for favorite apps and folders?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts

I access certain programs and folders frequently, I would like to access them with some shortcuts. For example I would like to open my Projects folder by typing pro.

In Windows, I have a folder that is in PATH with shortcuts to my favorite apps and folders. For Project folder, I have a shortcut pro, and if I type "pro" in run dialog it will open Project folder in explorer.

Is there a way I can mimic shortcuts folder and run dialog in Ubuntu?

Comment: check this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/331632/283843. But instead of typing "firefox" type `xdg-open /path/to/your/favorite/folder` and make a shortcut key to that.

Comment: For nautilus bookmarks see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293898/nautilus-bookmarks-are-missing-since-upgrade-to-13-04